# R hangs after finishing running a JAR

Tags: java, r

I have an r script that calls a jar like this:

```
system("java -cp myJar.jar com.myMainClass arg1 arg2", intern=TRUE)
```

I can "see" the java code executing (cpu jumps and disk writes), which outputs a text file with the results of the computation.
The next line of r reads in the results:

```
scores <- read.csv(results.csv, header=TRUE)
```

However there is a large gap, 10-30 seconds, between the java code writing out the file and r reading the file and continuing. The results file is small and the read by itself is lightning fast.

My question is two fold: What could be causing this and what could I do to speed things up? In terms of speeding things up I am curious about other methods of passing data to a java program and reading data back, without coupling the java to R.

Comment: The problem is that your Java and your R programs are running at the same time, so your R program have to *wait* until the Java program finishes the file writing. If you want to speed up the Java program, you can post your Java code in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some help (maybe here, but you can't just ask *how to speed up my program*, it will surely be down voted and closed). If you want to pass data between two programs you can use external files, pipes, sockets, database, etc... each one has its own pros/cons and it's up to you to choose the best technique for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your java program is closing the file properly, and shutting down all running threads.

Comment: Its closing the file properly but I am not sure if it is shutting down all running threads. Do you have to do more than just call return at the end of your threads computation?

Comment: Are you answering a question with another question? If you want to comment OP's question then please wait until you have enough rep and do it.

Comment: That was a very helpful comment though :)

Comment: Fair enough Luiggi. Editted my answer so not phrased as a question.

Comment: It was threads not shutting down. Called shutdown on the thread pool, and the thing runs quick as anything :) thanks!